# Checkboxes in long table not working

Tags: hyperref, enumerate

I'm trying to create a hyperref Checkbox-list in a long table (c.f. Code below). However, whenever I open the pdf-Document and check e.g. the first box all first boxes of the list are checked. My goal is that only the box I actually check gets checked and not all Checkboxes. I've searched for hours and didn't find a solution to this.

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} 
\hline
Time & ToDo \\ \hline \hline

9am - 10am & 
\begin{enumerate}[label = {\mbox{\CheckBox[height=0.5cm,width=0.5cm, name=test\theenumi]{}} }]

\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}
 \\ \hline


10am - 12am &
\begin{enumerate}[label = {\mbox{\CheckBox[height=0.5cm,width=0.5cm]{}} }]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2 \end{enumerate}
\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the issue you describe. If I make your code compilable and open the resulting pdf I can check a single checkbox or as many as I want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes with the same name are always  checked und unchecked at the same time. If you want independent checkboxes you have to ensure that they have different names. You can set the name with the `name` key and by adding suitable prefixes. Try e.g. here which checkboxes are checked together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\begin{enumerate}[label = {\mbox{\CheckBox[height=0.5cm,width=0.5cm,name=\theenumi]{~}} }]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label = {\mbox{\CheckBox[height=0.5cm,width=0.5cm,name=\theenumi]{~}} }]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label = {\mbox{\CheckBox[height=0.5cm,width=0.5cm,name=x\theenumi]{~}} }]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```